# Hive converting int column to string and to the target type: date

Tags: sql, types, hive

I have a problem with conversion of datatypes in hiveql. Data type of a column is int, it should be converted to date, but there is no direct conversion function from int to date. At first I converted int into string and it worked as below:

[image]

From this moment I based on the second column where I have my data converted to string. When I try to use ***cast(string as date)***, then the third column returns only nulls:

[image]

[image]

What is interesting, there is no problem when the string value to be converted was typed manually by a user:

[image]

Does anyone of You know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: SELECT 
cda_date, 
cast(concat_ws('-', substr(cda_date,0,4),substr(cda_date,5,2),substr(cda_date,7,2)) as date)
FROM database_name.table_name
GO

Comment: Solved as above.

Answer (score 0):

your method in the comment is quite good.

One more approach using regexp_replace:

```
select date(regexp_replace(cda_date,'^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})','$1-$2-$3'))
```